# How to make flutter run in android studio without any devices (real or virtual)?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I want to print some output to the **Console in Android Studio** without connecting ***any*** device.

I know flutter is super fast and the answer is "just plug it in, you moron" or "add a virtual device".

But I want to know if something like is possible or not? (thanks)

Comment: Maybe you just want to write some tests

Comment: Perhaps you want to just run some code in Dart

Comment: yes exactly, as both of u said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a ***temporary*** solution: (it's the closest I can get)

I added the "***Dart-sdk\bin***" to my SystemVariables and from the terminal inside Android studio I run the command "**dart** *.\THE_NAME_OF_MY_TEST_FILE*".

### Some notes:

1. the Dart sdk path must end with "**\bin**"
2. the Dart sdk directory is inside flutter's, "**PATH_TO_FLUTTER\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin**"
3. of course any terminal can be used not just android studio's (**BUT** make sure u r in the right directory before running the dart command, you have to be in the same directory as the target file of course).